# Different behavior of overriding methods and fields

Tags: java

I just noticed that overriding methods does behave different than overriding fields.
Considering the following snippet:

```
public class Bar {
  int v =1;

  public void printAll(){
    System.out.println(v);
    printV();
  }

  public void printV(){
    System.out.println("v is " + v);
  }
}

public class Foo extends Bar {
  int v = 4;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.printAll();
 }

 public void printV() {
   System.out.println("The value v is  " + v);
 }
}
```

It result in the output:
1
The value v is  4

So it seems that the method printV in bar is overridden by foo.printV while the field v is not overwritten in bar. Does anyone know a reason for this difference?

Thanks.

Comment: there is no such thing as field overriding in java. the output is correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I just noticed that overriding methods does behave different than overriding fields.

There's no such thing as "overriding fields". You can *shadow* fields, but you can't override them. Fields aren't polymorphic. See [section 6.4.1 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1) for more details.

Note that in general, fields should almost *always* be private anyway, which means you wouldn't be aware of this in the first place.

Comment: +1 fields of the same name can be different types in sub-classes, methods can only return more restrictive types in sub-classes.

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling 
foo.printAll();
It is calling the function of the base class which is printing the value 1.
Then you are calling printV.This time since the inherited class has a function of the same name, it is overridden and printV of Foo is called.

The value of v depends on from which class you are printing the value.