# Trying to understand how to override methods/variables

Tags: java

So I'm trying to understand overriding before I get to deep into my lesson. I watched TheNewBoston (bucky) explain overriding but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right. Would someone please spot check me and set me on the right path?

I don't remember bucky having to make any of his instance variables in his superclass protected. But when I was building my subclasses, eclipse made me convert my instance variables to protected.

Superclass Contacts:

```
public class Contacts
{
    protected String fname;
    protected String lname;
    protected String email;
    protected String phone;

    public Contacts(String fname, String lname, String email, String phone)
    {
        this.fname=fname;
        this.lname=lname;
        this.email=email;
        this.phone=phone;

    }

    public String getfname()
    {
        return fname;
    }

    public void setfname(String first)
    {
        this.fname=first;       
    }

    public String getlname()
    {
        return lname;
    }

    public void setlname(String last)
    {
        this.lname=last;
    }

    public String getemail()
    {
        return email;
    }

    public void setemail(String e)
    {
        this.email=e;
    }

    public String getphone()
    {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setphone(String num)
    {
        this.phone=num;
    }

    public String getFullName()
    {
        String full=fname+" "+lname;
        return full;
    }
```

subclass Friend:

```
public class Friend extends Contacts
{
    private String dob;


    public Friend(String fname, String lname, String email, String phone)
    {
        super(fname, lname, email, phone);
    }


    public String getDob()
    {
        return dob;
    }


    public void setDob(String dob)
    {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return fname+", "+lname+", "+email+", "+phone+", "+dob;
    }




}
```

subclass BusinessAssociate:

```
public class BusinessAssociate extends Contacts
{
    private String title;
    private String position;
    private String company;
    private String full;

    public BusinessAssociate(String fname, String lname, String email,
            String phone)
    {
        super(fname, lname, email, phone);

    }

    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title)
    {
        this.title=title;
    }

    public String getCompany()
    {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(String company)
    {
        this.company=company;
    }

    public String getPosition()
    {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(String position)
    {
        this.position=position;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see Contacts#getFullName()
     */
    @Override
    public String getFullName()
    {
        full=title+" "+fname+" "+lname;
        return full;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return full+", "+email+", "+phone+", "+company+", "+position;
    }




}
```

Comment: Is your question about declaring the fields/methods as `protected` or *not having* any scope at all?

Comment: Eclipse probably recommended that you switch your parent class variables to `protected`, because you are directly referencing the them in your subclasses. Which you shouldn't do - use the accessor (get) methods instead.

Comment: @Perception that's not a problem indeed.

Comment: but why did eclipse make me put the constructor in each subclass. It wasn't that way on the youtube video's.

Comment: @ElizabethTurner: your super class does not have a default no-arg constructor, and so you must explicitly call the super constructor in the child constructors. Else Java tries to call the super's default no arg constructor, but since that doesn't exist -- error!

Comment: It would be better if you edit your post and place **your questions** in order to answer them. Also, the link when you see this overriding explanation could help.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels how do I change my super class to no-arg constructor?

Comment: Elizabeth: I wouldn't get rid of the current super constructor as it is quite useful, but you could create a second constructor, one with an empty set of parenthesis, but inside of this constructor, be sure to set all fields to some default values.

Comment: There's a thing with scopes, if your classes are in the same package, then you would be able to access the fields in the subclasses without any problem, that is called `default` scope but if they are in a different package, you need a wider scope, such as `protected` or `public`

Comment: @RodrigoSasaki `protected` indeed.

Comment: Yeah, @LuiggiMendoza. I figured they were in different packages, but things are really hard to analyze here, there's no package definition we can see. And there's no real question here so we can answer to keep Q&A format.

Comment: @RodrigoSasaki I know, but seems OP thinks as this site as a forum (most newcomers do it). Elizabeth, again, please specify your questions about this code and we will happily help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overrides in your code look correct to me.

But note that you can only override instance methods.  Constructors, fields and static methods *cannot* be overridden.

A comment asks:

> What do you mean by "fields cannot be overridden"? This looks like an override to me:
>
> ```
>     class A { protected int a = 1; } 
>     class B extends A { protected int a = 2; }`.
> ```
>
> Can you please clarify this?

That is not an override.  What you have here is a field in the subclass `B` that *hides* the field in the superclass `A`.  If you create an instance of `B` it will have two distinct `a` fields, with different values.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11971061/139985

---

> ... but why did eclipse make me put the constructor in each subclass. It wasn't that way on the youtube video's.

Because Eclipse implements the JLS, and the JLS requires it.  Presumably there is something different about the example in the YouTube video.

The way your example is designed, the base class `Contacts` has fields that are common to / used by the subclasses, and it (naturally) initializes those fields in its constructor.  You don't (and shouldn't) have a no-args constructor in `Contacts` because that would allow people to create useless `Constants` instances that have `null` name, email and phone fields.

However, the fact that `Contacts` has no no-args constructors means that any subclass needs an explicit constructor declaration.  The way Java works, if you don't declare any constructors, a class gets a default no-args constructor.  But that default constructor is only possible if the superclass has a no0args constructor.  In this case, it doesn't.

So Eclipse was correct in insisting that your subclasses declared constructors.  The Java compiler would also have been happy with the alternative of adding a no-args constructor to `Contacts`.  But that would be the wrong solution, because it would result in `BusinessAssociate` and `Friend` instances being created with `null` fields.

---

> But when I was building my subclasses, eclipse made me convert my instance variables to protected.

It is not entirely clear why that happened ('cos we don't know what you had before!!), but if your subclasses refer directly to fields of the superclass, then the superclass fields must have the right "access" modifiers to allow this.  (For instance, a subclass cannot ever refer directly to a superclasses `private` fields.  The Java Language Specification forbids this.)

Comment: What do you mean by *"fields cannot be overriden"*? This looks ilke an override to me: `class A {
    protected int a = 1;
}

class B extends A {
    protected int a = 2;
}`. Can you please clarify this? Thanks.